# which eclispe should be downloaded to automate angular js application

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to automate `Angular JS` application by using `eclipse`? If so, which `version` should I try?
Also, what are the languages I need to know before doing that.
I downloaded `Angular JS` from `Help-->Eclipse Marketplace-->AngularJS`
But somehow I feel like I am unable to connect the dots.
Please suggest me on this.

Comment: What do you mean with "to automate Angular JS application using eclipse"? Please clarify.

Comment: I am currently working in a application which is built on Angular JS. I would like to write automation for testing the application. I would like to know end to end steps on how to configure eclipse to test angular js applications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but if you have already installed Angular IDE into Eclipse, that's the most you can do from it. It supports projects, syntax and error handling in Ajs. In comment you've mentioned testing angular js application. Like every other website, you can use JUnit or TestNG automatic tests to verify work of your application. If you dont like approach from Eclipse, you can use Selenium IDE test that runs throught Mozilla Firefox.

[image]
On picture above you can enable or disable Angular support for your project.